# Nginx weird routing behaviour

Tags: reactjs, spring, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have encountered a weird nginx routing behaviour, i have 2 BE services running along with a client application, both BE services are getting called from my client.

having following nginx config, API calls towards both services does work successfully:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name memorial-hub.de;

proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
proxy_read_timeout 86400;

location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}

location ^~ /api/v1 {
    proxy_pass http://authentication-service:9003;
}

location ^~ /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://service:9002;
}
```

}

i have tried to change my authentication service prefix to separate concerns:

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name memorial-hub.de;

    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location ^~ /auth-api {
        rewrite /auth-api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://authentication-service:9003;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    location ^~ /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://service:9002;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        
    }
}
```

now having adjusted my auth service, it does receive the API calls but returns a HTTP 403 ?

Althought running exactly the same API call locally does work successfully.

Now i am confused why this behaviour happen.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It turns out that my CI/CD was not deploying a new backend .jar but the old one after adding changes to it.

the nginx conf was fine